# How to create dynamic html table from a xml file

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a requirement to create a dynamic table from an xml file similar to below, where I can use `xpath` or similar to show `filesystem` content in it, with proper variable pagination, filtering, sort and selection of particular row.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="csmclientiir.xsl"?>
<csmclient product="abc"   date="4/26/11 2:05 PM">
<system>
    <osname>Linux
    </osname>
    <hostname>AbhishekNix
    </hostname>
    <release>2.6.18-128.el5
    </release>
    <filesystem>
        <file mount='/home/hp1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/hp1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/par21' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/par21)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/h231' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/h231)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/avallin1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/avallin1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/park' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/park)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/sp1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/sp1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/ganga1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/ganga1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/nbp1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/nbp1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
    </filesystem>
</system>
<product>
    <showtime>Tue Apr 26 14:05:23 2011
    </showtime>
</product>
</csmclient>
```

**Edited**

Here is what I used using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

```
jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid({
    url: cpath, 
    datatype: "xml",
    colNames:["Total Space","Free Space","Used Space", "Used Percentage"], 
    colModel:[ {name:"Total Space",index:"Total Space", width:90, xmlmap:"system>filesystem>file>@total"},
               {name:"Free Space",index:"Free Space", width:120, xmlmap:"system>filesystem>file>@free"},
               {name:"Used Space",index:"Used Space", width:180,xmlmap:"system>filesystem>file>@used"},
               {name:"Used Percentage",index:"Used Percentage", width:100, align:"right",xmlmap:"system>filesystem>file>@percentage", sorttype:"float"}
             ],
    height:250,
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30], 
    viewrecords: true, 
    gridview: true,
    loadonce: true, 
    xmlReader: { 
        root : "csmclient",
        row: "system>filesystem",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "ASIN"
        },
    caption: "Disk Usage"
    });
```

it only shows heading without any data

**Note**: my xml file structure is fixed

Comment: Do you have a sample of what you would like your output to be? Have you attempted it or do you just want a full solution?

Comment: @Ben: I attempted it using `spry` which works perfectly, but I am asked to use only one technology so I was using jquery a lot so had to stick solely with jQuery i'll edit my question to include a sample

Comment: Doesn't http://www.datatables.net/ do the trick?

Comment: @MiPnamic: from  what i tried and read, their xml formatting requirements are strict.

Comment: @Ricky umh, I never tried with pure xml, I use php for "serve" data to datatables. but this mean for you to "read" the xml and "compose it" for Datatables

Comment: @MiPnamic: I am lost totally.. :) please can you give any example link?

Comment: @MiPnamic: I followed @doctrey and edited my question. please take a look

Comment: @altCognito: can you take a look her please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I used [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) for a project but I was using JSON instead of XML as it's data.
But this plugin also accepts the XML type of data. It's pretty dynamic and have all the functionalities you want. You might want to check the [demo here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). There's a section named Data Mapping which explains how to map XML files.

**Comment on the edit**
I would change your code this way:

```
 xmlReader: {
    root : "filesystem",
    row: "file",
    repeatitems: false,
 }
```

Since I guess it's the file attributes you want to show in a single row. Also make sure the `colModel` `name` maps to the name of your node. I still don't know if you could map node attributes but assuming you do:

```
    colModel:[ {name:"total",index:"total", width:90},
           {name:"free",index:"free", width:120},
           {name:"used",index:"used"},
           {name:"percentage",index:"percentage", width:100, sorttype:"float"}
         ]
```

This [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs) is also useful it can help you to start with jqGrid.

Comment: jqGrid looks like a great find. Bookmarked for future reference. +1

Comment: @doctrey: Can you give me some link that u used for Data Mapping for mapping xml files

Comment: @doctrey: How to use an attribute, in your link there are only node texts

Comment: @Ricky As I said I used JSON as my data but it shouldn't make any difference after all. Just map each column with your xml nodes. Follow the example in the demo page.

Comment: @Ricky I think if you want to show the attributes you need to rewrite your XML as each attribute becomes a child node under `file`. Again I might be wrong cause I have not used XML with this plugin.

Comment: @doctrey: please check out my edited question, also my xml structure is fixed I cannot change it